# Fetch with React on codesandbox : cross-origin error

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, codesandbox

I have the following fetch call in a React app on codesandbox :
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fetch-example-for-so-vxxie

If I activate either line

`.then(console.log(data))`

or

`loadOptions={this.state.data}`

I get :
*A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See https:// fb.me/react-crossorigin-error for more information.*

Why and how to troubleshoot this ?

(please note I added a space in front of fb.me to pass validation here on StackOverflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly from what universe the error message comes from, but `.then(console.log(data))` cannot work, because `data` is not defined. You would rather want

```
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

and still the next `.then` would fail because it requires the result from the above to perform its task, so you'd do this, which works for me in your sandbox example:

```
.then(data => { console.log(data); return data; })
```

Comment: Thank you @JulienD
Your answer helped me move on and I was able to make the whole example work eventually using react-select v3 : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-v3-asyncselect-fetch-ewlib